# how to transfer app and service data from one predix account to another

Tags: cloud-foundry, predix

I have an account on predix which contain number of apps and services.
I want to transfer this data to my new account before deleting the previous account.
How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For services you might want to recreate in the new account because they are linked to your zone id of the old account. For apps you might be able to deploy to the new org/space and re-bind to the new services. I'm not sure if there is currently a "transfer" functionality.

Links that might be helpful:

https://cloud.gov/docs/apps/moving-apps/

https://forum.predix.io/questions/19246/migrate-from-one-org-to-another.html